# How pass ref to my child inside my React 's class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen that to push your ref to children you have to use `React.forwardRef`, okay but from the examples I have seen the forwardRef's function is used outside the React class. However I want to summon the ref inside the React's class in order to **pass the ref to the component inside my React's class**.

How handle that?

Here my react snippet:

```
render() {  
        console.log("object of pizzaPortofilio: ", this)         
        return (
            <div className={style.component} >
                <div onClick={()=> console.log("test :)")}
                >test </div>
                <div className={style.vertical_navigation} > 
                        <ContentMenu
                            accueilRef={this.accueil.current}
                            menuRef={this.menu.current}
                            testimonyRef={this.testimony.current}
                            reservationRef={this.reservation.current}
                            adressRef={this.adress.current}
                            contactRef={this.contact.current}
                        />
                </div>

                <div className={style.content_container} > 
                    <div className={style.top_info}> 

                        <p id={style.top_info_hour}> Click to display hours </p>
                        <p id={style.top_info_telephone}> +511-941-243 </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Accueil ref={this.accueil} />
                    </div>
                    {
                        <div>
                            <Menu ref={this.menu} />
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div id={style.social_proof} >
                        <SocialProof ref={this.testimony}/>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{marginTop:"15vh"}}>
                        <BookUtil ref={this.reservation}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Adress ref={this.adress}/>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{marginTop:"20vh"}}>
                        <Contact ref={this.contact}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

when I pass the ref in the console log of children as following:

> console.log("this.props.accueilRef: ", this.props.accueilRef.current)

it return me an object.

But,
when I m trying to get the bounding as following:

> console.log("this.props.accueilRef.current.getBoundingClientRect: ",
>   this.props.accueilRef.current.getBoundingClientRect())

it returns me the following error:

> Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

how transmit my ref to my children implemented in my React's class? Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: You won't get `current` of any `ref` till the ref is set. So, try to check if `current` has value by doing something like this: `(this.someRef.current && this.someRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()) ||  {}`

Comment: Also, refs on components return the component, not the components dom element. Meaning, `getBoundingClientRect` won't work, unless your component has a function of that name. `<div ref={...` would work fine, since that returns the `<div/>`